# Failed to execute maven-plugin-plugin on Java 9

Tags: java, maven, java-9, javalite

I'm trying to migrate [JavaLite](http://javalite.io/) projects to Java9, but getting this exception during a build.

The module that fails (so far) is: 
https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc-instrumentation/pom.xml

**My environment:**

**Ubuntu Linux:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

**Java:**

```
java -version
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

**Maven:**

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T14:39:06-05:00)
Maven home: /home/igor/programs/apache-maven-3.5.0
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/igor/programs/jdk-9
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-89-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Exception I get during the build:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project activejdbc-instrumentation: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 62209 -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) on project activejdbc-instrumentation: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 62209
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-descriptor of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor failed: 62209
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 62209
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scanDirectory(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:205)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.scanner.DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.scan(DefaultMojoAnnotationsScanner.java:95)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.scanAnnotations(JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.annotations.JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.execute(JavaAnnotationsMojoDescriptorExtractor.java:104)
        at org.apache.maven.tools.plugin.scanner.DefaultMojoScanner.populatePluginDescriptor(DefaultMojoScanner.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.AbstractGeneratorMojo.execute(AbstractGeneratorMojo.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.plugin.DescriptorGeneratorMojo.execute(DescriptorGeneratorMojo.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :activejdbc-instrumentation
```

Comment: Go to the most recent versions of plugins otherwise JDK 9 will not work...but there existing some issues at the moment: See here: https://s.apache.org/maven-j9 (Also wise to subscribe to dev list and ask)...If you find further issue please report on the dev list for this...

Answer (score 4):

From [this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw), it appears that the minimum version for maven-plugin-plugin is v 3.5 re: Java 9. I am not a "Maven maven" but the log output implies v 3.2.

Generally, one will need to carefully check versions for many build tools and their plugins. Legacy versions for Maven, Gradle, and respective plugins might not "just work"; there has been effort by these teams to be ready for Java 9. i.e. updates

Comment: that makes sense. My poms do not even mention that plugin. I will look into it and report back.